# Programatically Changing Entry Types?

Tags: plugin-development, entries, craft3

I have a **people channel** that historically has used another field to decide if they're a "featured" person or not.

The field set for "**featured**" people has now diverged from what a normal person has, so I'm wanting to create a new entry type in the people channel (**featuredPeople**) and programatically shift these people to the new entry type.

The field set is additive to the old one, so I'm hoping due to there being no field/structural changes this isn't too hard?

I've got the bones of a script together to do this, but I'm struggling to find any info on how to actually change the entry type on the entry.

```php
# Get all people
$peopleCrit = Entry::find();
$peopleCrit->section = "people";
$people = $peopleCrit->all() ?? [];

foreach ($people as $person) {

    # If this was a "featured" person, shift to new featuredPeople entry type.
    if (historical "is featured" check) {

        # Move to featuredPeople entry type
        ???

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. I've also cleaned up the code a bit to be correct PHP syntax as my assumption is that you''ll be doing this in a module/plugin.

```
// Get all people entries
$entries = Entry::find()->section('people')->all();

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // If this was a "featured" historical person
    if ($entry->historical == 'featured') {
        // Change to featuredPeople entry type
        $entry->typeId = $featuredPeopleEntryTypeId;

        // Save entry
        Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben. That was pseudocode as the historical featured check is a complicated piece of logic on its own. However, just changing the typeId and re-saving does appear to have worked. The field data appears to be intact. I super didn't expect it to be that easy. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, it's that simple :)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference of anybody stumbling onto this post (like me), setting ->typeId works for like 90%, but to cover it all put this in it too:

```
$entry->fieldLayoutId = null;
```

If you don't throw the field layout out, it might still hold on to the old fields of the entry. This gives some really weird issues, like a relational field being filled in the cp, but in twig the field doesn't exist